# ¿Como hacer que el elemento que este centrado en el recyclerview este seleccionado?

Tags: android-studio, recyclerview

Con el uso de `recyclerview` estoy haciendo un calendario, y lo que quiero hacer es de que cuando el usuario se deslize hacia abajo o hacia arriba el elemento que pase por el centro se pueda fijar y considerar que esta seleccionado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede apreciar el numero que pasa por el marcador no se fija dentro de el.

Aqui les dejo el codigo hasta donde tengo hecho:

widget_bottom_sheet_fecha_nacimiento.xml:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView19"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imageView_contentDescription"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_drag_handle_grey700_20dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:divider="@drawable/divisor_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:showDividers="middle"
        android:weightSum=".9"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".9"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView19"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="1">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView19">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView30"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:paddingStart="30dp"
                android:paddingEnd="30dp"
                android:text="@string/textView_acceso_recuperar_contrasena_busqueda_avanzada_buscar_cuenta_calendar_titulo"
                android:textColor="@color/Grey800"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView31"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView20"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".5"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".7" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView31"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:paddingStart="30dp"
                android:paddingEnd="30dp"
                android:text="@string/textView_acceso_recuperar_contrasena_busqueda_avanzada_buscar_cuenta_calendar_subtitulo"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView30"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".5"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView30"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView30"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".7" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView20"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/imageView_contentDescription"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_calendar_black_30dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="1"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView30"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".3" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:baselineAligned="false"
                android:divider="@drawable/divisor_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:showDividers="middle"
                android:weightSum=".9"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".3">

                    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/recyclerView_Dia"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:clipToPadding="false"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        tools:listitem="@layout/item_bottom_sheet_fecha_nacimiento" />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/view4"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:alpha=".4"
                        android:background="@drawable/select_dia_calendar"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
                        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".35"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
                        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".95" />
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".3">

                    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/recyclerView_Mes"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/view5"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:alpha=".4"
                        android:background="@drawable/select_mes_calendar"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
                        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".35"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
                        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="1" />
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".3">

                    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/recyclerView_Year"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/view6"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:alpha=".4"
                        android:background="@drawable/select_year_calendar"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
                        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".35"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
                        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".95" />
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".2"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_Aceptar"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_corners_oval_transparent"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:text="@string/button_aceptar"
                android:textColor="@color/tea700"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".8"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn_Cancelar"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".4" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_Cancelar"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_corners_oval_transparent"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:text="@string/button_cancelar"
                android:textColor="@color/Red800"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_Aceptar"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn_Aceptar"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".8"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btn_Aceptar"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".4" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

RecyclerAdapterCalendario.java:

```
public class RecyclerAdapterCalendario extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapterCalendario.ViewHolderItem> {

// region Variables

private Context context;
private ArrayList<ItemCalendario> listaValues;

// endregion

// region Constructor

public RecyclerAdapterCalendario(Context context, ArrayList<ItemCalendario> listaValues) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listaValues = listaValues;
}

// endregion

// region CallBack System

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolderItem onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    final View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_bottom_sheet_fecha_nacimiento, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolderItem(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolderItem holder, int position) {
    holder.textView.setText(listaValues.get(position).getValue());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listaValues.size();
}

// endregion

// region SuperClass

public class ViewHolderItem extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView textView;

    public ViewHolderItem(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtView);
    }
}

// endregion
}
```

Fragment.java:

```
private void mostrarCalendario() {
    final View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.widget_bottom_sheet_fecha_nacimiento, null);
    final Button buttonAceptar = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_Aceptar);
    final Button buttonCancelar = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_Cancelar);
    final LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    buttonAceptar.setClipToOutline(true);
    buttonCancelar.setClipToOutline(true);

    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        listaValues.add(new ItemCalendario(String.valueOf(i)));
    }

    adapterCalendario = new RecyclerAdapterCalendario(getContext(), listaValues);
    recyclerViewDias = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_Dia);
    recyclerViewDias.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerViewDias.setAdapter(adapterCalendario);
    recyclerViewDias.setLayoutManager(manager);
    bottomSheetDialogCalendario.setContentView(view);
    bottomSheetDialogCalendario.setCancelable(false);
    bottomSheetDialogCalendario.create();
    bottomSheetDialogCalendario.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya no es necesario establecer el layoutManger en el codigo java, se puede establecer directamente en el xml:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/recyclerView_Dias"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:clipToPadding="false"
                        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        tools:listitem="@layout/item_bottom_sheet_fecha_nacimiento" />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/view4"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:alpha=".4"
                        android:background="@drawable/select_dia_calendar"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
                        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".35"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
                        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".95" />

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Para poder centrar un elemento mientras se desliza el recyclerView utilizar:

```
SnapHelper snapHelperDias = new LinearSnapHelper();
snapHelperDias.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerViewDias);
```

Quedando:

```
private void mostrarCalendario() {
    final View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.widget_bottom_sheet_fecha_nacimiento, null);
    final Button buttonAceptar = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_Aceptar);
    final Button buttonCancelar = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_Cancelar);
    final LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    buttonAceptar.setClipToOutline(true);
    buttonCancelar.setClipToOutline(true);

    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        listaValues.add(new ItemCalendario(String.valueOf(i)));
    }

    adapterCalendario = new RecyclerAdapterCalendario(getContext(), listaValues);
    recyclerViewDias = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_Dia);
    recyclerViewDias.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerViewDias.setAdapter(adapterCalendario);
    SnapHelper snapHelperDias = new LinearSnapHelper();
    snapHelperDias.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerViewDias);
    bottomSheetDialogCalendario.setContentView(view);
    bottomSheetDialogCalendario.setCancelable(false);
    bottomSheetDialogCalendario.create();
    bottomSheetDialogCalendario.show();
}
```